# AWK; difference between dates

Tags: awk

Below is how my file looks like:

```
name_1|group_10|2017-08-27|2017-09-02
name_2|group_15|2018-05-05|2018-06-11
name_2|group_21|2018-06-11|2018-06-11
name_1|group_43|2020-08-14|2020-08-20
```

I am trying to use `awk` to get the difference between two dates from two columns (for same ID that can have multiple instances)

For the first instance of each name in `$1`, take the corresponding value from `$4` and then check for the next instance of the same name and take the corresponding value from `$3` and if the difference between `($4-$3) <=2` days then create a new column `$5` and print `TRUE`.

```
name_1|group_1026|2017-08-27|2017-09-02
name_2|group_1566|2018-05-05|2018-06-11|TRUE
name_2|group_2124|2018-06-11|2018-06-11
name_1|group_4391|2020-08-14|2020-08-20
```

So I am trying to do this

```
awk -F "|" '{if (($4-$3)<=2) print $5="TRUE"}' OFS="|" file
```

for `name_1`, `$4==2017-09-02` (from first instance) and `$3==2020-08-14` (from last instance)

Any help on this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are there always 2 instances of each name?

Comment: @anubhava, there could be multiple instances of each name in `$1`.

Comment: Then how to calculate date difference? Is it always between current entry and next entry for a name?

Comment: @anubhava, yes. if there are 4 entries of name_1 then:  calculate the date difference between first and second, second and third, third and fourth and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `gnu awk` script:

```sh
cat dtcmp.awk

function epoch(dt) {
   return mktime(gensub(/-/, " ", "g", dt) " 0 0 0")
}
BEGIN {FS=OFS="|"}
# while processing file first time
FNR == NR {
   if ($3 != "" && $4 != "") {
      if ($1 in arr) {
         # if $1 is in arr then compute difference in epoch values
         # of $4 and $3 and store it in diff array with key as
         # ($1,recordNo)
         v3 = epoch($3)
         diff[$1,ind[$1]] = (arr[$1] > v3 ? arr[$1] - v3 : v3 - arr[$1]) / 86400
      }
      # store epoch value of $4 in arr with $1 as key
      arr[$1] = epoch($4)
      # store current record no. in ind with $1 as key
      ind[$1] = FNR
   }
   next
}
# if ($1,recordNo) is found in diff then append diff to a record
$3 == "" || $4 == "" || ($1,FNR) in diff {
   $0 = $0 OFS diff[$1,FNR]
} 1
```

And use it as:

```
awk -f dtcmp.awk file file

name_1|group_10|2017-08-27|2017-09-02|1077
name_2|group_15|2018-05-05|2018-06-11|0
name_2|group_21|2018-06-11|2018-06-11
name_1|group_43|2020-08-14|2020-08-20
```

Comment: I guess I need to install `gwak`?

Comment: Thank you. it worked. Is it possible to print the DIFFERENCE (number of days) rather than `TRUE`.

Comment: I have one question here: how can I change your code when $3>$4`. It works fine when `$3==$4` but not when `$3>$4`. So imagine I change `$3` in row from `2018-06-11` to `2018-06-12`. Any clues?

Comment: could you please add a brief explanation of your code at your convenince? Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Anubhava, will you be kind enough to address one more question re this? How can I avoid columns that have missing values in `$3` or `$4`? I know I can make a subset of the file where there are no missing values but I wanted to apply it to my original file. If you could just give me a hint that would be of great help. thank you

Comment: I have added code to skip if `$3` or `$4` are empty. Also I have added explanation in comments.

Comment: thank you! I think I did not explain my question well. If `$3` or `$4` are blank then I want to ignore them while calculating the difference between dates but still want to have them in the output.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk. This reverses the file, processes it, and re-reverses it:

```sh
tac file | gawk '
    BEGIN { FS = OFS = "|"; twoDays = 86400 * 2 }
    function date2epoch(date) {
        return mktime(gensub(/-/, " ", "g", date) " 0 0 0")
    }
    function abs(val) {
        return val < 0 ? -val : val
    }
    ($1 in prev) && abs(date2epoch($4) - prev[$1]) <= twoDays { 
        $(NF+1) = "TRUE"
    }
    { print;  prev[$1] = date2epoch($3) }
' | tac
```

My thinking for reversing the file: instead of processing the *current* line based on a *subsequent* line that I haven't seen yet, process the current line based on a *previous* line that I can remember.

---

If you want to save this as a script, save it as a *shell* script: what I posted is a pipeline of 3 commands: `tac | gawk | tac`

```sh
#!/bin/sh
tac "$1" | gawk '
    awk body as above
' | tac
```

Then you can run it like

```sh
sh myscript.sh myfile
```

Comment: @ glenn jackman, it works! thank you. could you please add a brief explanation of your code at your convenience? Thank you!